# Dynamically Generate HTML Div's and Insert Data into Database

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have image when i click on it the value is store in x and y variable using jquery also the image part name like x=120 y =230 Name=Tea Cup

```
var x = event.pageX;
var y = event.pageY;
```

I can click on the image any number of time and fill the X,y, and Name value

```
$("#textboxX").append('<div><input type="text" value="' + x + '" id="txtX" name="txtX"/></div>');
$("#textboxY").append('<div><input type="text" value="' + y + '" id="txtY" name="txtY"/></div>');
$("#textboxBPart").append("<div><input type='text' id='txtName' name='txtName'/></div>");

var $r = $('<button />', { type: 'button', text: 'Add Data to Div', id: 'btn_addToDiv' });
var $cancle = $('<button />', { type: 'button', text: 'Cancle', id: 'btn_cancle' });

var $DBInsert = $('<button />', { type: 'button', text: 'Add Data to Database', id: 'btn_addToDB' });
$("#divSaveDynamicDis").append($r);
$("#divSaveDynamicDis").append($cancle);
```

Now this value get appended to div

```
var NewData = '<div class="col-sm-12">' + x + '   ' + y + '  ' + txtName.value + ' &nbsp; <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF" data-marker="m_' + x + '_' + y + '">Remove</a> </div>';

$("#<%= divdynamicData.ClientID %>").append(NewData);
```

i want to insert this 5 10 15 50 DIV records to database using the button name btn_addToDB. What i suppose to do now need suggestion
need help

Comment: You can use ajax to post data on your server .

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.btn_addToDB').click(function(){ 
   $.post('Path',DataVariable, function(res){
       if(res){
           alert("Ajax call completed")
       }
   });
});
```

Comment: thank sir for your reply i am new to juqery. i will follow your suggestion

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation or details to your answer. While it might answer the question, just adding a piece of code as an answer, doesn't per say help OP or future community members understand the issue or the proposed solution.